# Right column doesn't go to the bottom of the body

Tags: css, html

Hey there I currently have the following website (screenshot) :

http://postimage.org/image/25ahko3b8/

What I am wanting is for my right column to stretch all the way to the bottom of the body (even if there is not enough content to push it down).

How can I achieve this with my CSS?

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="swaggersstyle.css">
        <title>Oamaru Backpackers Hostel, Swaggers Backpackers - Home</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- include Cycle plugin --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script> 
</head>


<body>
    <img src="final.jpg" id="banner">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li class="links"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="links"><a href="planning.html">Location</a></li>
        <li class="links"><a href="construction.html">Facilities</a></li>
        <li class="links"><a href="evaluation.html">Attractions</a></li>
        <li id = "endlink"><a href="evaluation.html" id="lastlink">Bookings</a></li>
    </ul>


<div id="mainc">

    <p>Make Yourself at Home</p>
    <p>Swaggers Backpackers is a converted old house located within     walking distance of all the best parts of Oamaru. Explore the old   victorian era buildings and shops of the city centre, or see the    penguin colonies down the street. Swaggers is owned and operated    by camp mum Agra, who makes all guests feel welcome, informed,  and perhaps a bit mothered. </p>

    <div class="slideshow"> 
        <img src="1.jpg" width="600" height="450" /> 
        <img src="2.jpg" width="600" height="450" /> 
        <img src="3.jpg" width="600" height="450" /> 
    </div> 


</div>   

<div id="rightcolumn">
<p>hghadgadgadg</p>
<p>easfasf</p>
<p>safSFS</p>
<p>afafafadf</p>
<p>safasf</p>
<p>saasfasf</p>
<p>fasfsaf</p>
</div>

<div id ="footer">
<p> fsafasfasf </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color:#464E54;
}

body{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 0;
}

#banner{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

#nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
    border-top: 1px solid #7f7f7f;

}

#mainc {
    float: left;
    width: 654px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}

#rightcolumn {
    padding-left: 3px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    width: 290px;
    border-left: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0.5px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    border-top: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}

#footer p{
    margin: 0;
}

.links {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #7f7f7f;
}

#endlink {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border-right: none;
}

#lastlink{
    display: block;
    width: 184px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

a:link {

    display: block;
    width: 183px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

a:visited {

    display: block;
    width: 183px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #444444;
    background-color: #dad8bf;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #999999;
}

a:active{
    background-color: #999999;
}

.slideshow {
    height: 483px;
    width: 632px;
    margin: auto;
}

.slideshow img {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Just a side note - I want to be able to do this without setting a specified height if possible. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

it would be great if you could add your actual page rather than an image, but just do this:

first of all, you need a container div for both columns, let's say you name it container, then the CSS would be as follows:

```
#container{width:YOUR_WIDTH; height:auto; overflow: hidden;}
```

then we need to setup the columns. If you know the main column will be ALWAYS longer than the sidebar, then you don't need to do anything, otherwise apply this CSS to both columns:

```
#rightcolumn {
padding-left: 3px;
float: left; padding-bottom:50000px; margin-bottom:-50000px;
background-color: #dad8bf;
width: 290px;
border-left: 1px solid #7f7f7f;}
```

This is a technique I invented several years ago and became pretty known. The secret is to add the same padding and negative margin values. Since you have an overflow in your container, then the column will adjust to the max height available (determined by the longer column "pushing" the limits of the container box) and everything else will be hidden

Answer (score 0):

To do this, apply the `rightcolumn` background colour to the `mainc` div instead. Wrap the left column content inside a div and give it a white background. This will allow the right column to extend down as far as the left column.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Q96Z/

html

```
<div id="mainc">

    <div id="leftcolumn">
         <p>Make Yourself at Home</p>
         <p>Swaggers Backpackers is a converted old house located...</p>
         <div class="slideshow"> ... </div>
    </div>

    <div id="rightcolumn">
        <p>hghadgadgadg</p>
        <p>hghadgadgadg</p>
    </div>

</div>
```